# jQuery - Get values of weight and grade inputs and calculate the result based on the formula

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to write code that calculates the result of weight and grade inputs
based on the following formula

```
Weighted grade =
 = w1×g1+ w2×g2+ w3×g3
 = 30%×80+ 50%×90+ 20%×72 = 83.4
```

Here is my current code

```
    function total(){
    var grade = 0;  
    var weight = 0;  

    $("[name='grade']").each(function() {
        grade += Number(this.value);
    });
    $("[name='weight']").each(function() {
       weight += Number(this.value);
    });
    $(".results").text((weight * grade + weight * grade)/weight);
}
$("[name='grade'],[name='weight']").on("keyup", total);
total();
```

please check the following line and let me know if I need to do any edits to achieve the correct result

```
$(".results").text((weight * grade + weight * grade)/weight);
```

Comment: well you did not code that formula. `weight * grade` != `w1×g`

Comment: so, can you please help in correcting my code?

Comment: ```var grades = $("[name='grade']"); var weights = $("[name='weight']"); grades.each(function (index) {
   console.log(+this.value * +weights[eq].value));
})```

Answer (score 0):

From the question it is not quite clear whether you are dealing with *multiple grades* (and *results*) based on *one common set of weights* but the following solution is based on that assumption:

```js
const w=$("tfoot input").on("input",_=>trs.each((i,tr)=>calc.call(tr))).get();
      trs=$("tbody tr").on("input",calc);
function calc(){
 let wsum=w.reduce((a,c)=>+c.value+a,0);
 $(".results",this).text($("input",this).get().reduce((a,c,i)=>w[i].value*c.value+a,0)/wsum)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.min.js"></script>
<table><thead><tr><th>subj 1</th><th>subj 2</th><th>subj 3</th><th>results</th></tr></thead><tbody>
<tr><td><input type="text" name="grade"></td><td><input type="text" name="grade"></td><td><input type="text" name="grade"></td><td class="results"></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="text" name="grade"></td><td><input type="text" name="grade"></td><td><input type="text" name="grade"></td><td class="results"></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="text" name="grade"></td><td><input type="text" name="grade"></td><td><input type="text" name="grade"></td><td class="results"></td></tr>
<tr><th colspan="4">weights:</th></tr>
</tbody><tfoot>
<tr><td><input type="text" name="weight" value="30"></td><td><input type="text" name="weight" value="50"></td><td><input type="text" name="weight" value="20"></td><td class="results"></td></tr></tfoot></table>
```

The function `calc()` calculates the resulting weighted grade for the row of the table in which the input happened (identified by `this`). It is triggered by the "input" event for each `tbody tr` element. Whenever one of the weights changes *all* grading rows need to be recalculated. This is achieved by doing an `each`-loop over all `trs` (jQuery object). Each `tr` is assigned to the `this` of the `calc()` function by using the `Function.prototype.call()` method.